# Android Sdk Syntax Error

Tags: android

I am android starter and have problems with the syntax they show me every time a failure, so i hope anybody can help me here is my code:

```
public class VorherbestimmungenActivity extends Activity {
private ListView lv1;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
EditText inputSearch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vorherbestimmung);
    String products[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.vorherbestimmung);
    lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>
        parent, View view,
        int position, long id){
            switch( position)
            {
            case 0: Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);


            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

            String shareMessage = "";

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,""));
            break;
            default:
{

     inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
     lv1.setAdapter(adapter); 
     inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                VorherbestimmungenActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


     }
});
}
}
```

So this is the Code i used.
Here is the failure: Multiple markers at this line

```
- Syntax error, insert "}" to complete 
 MethodBody
- Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
 Expression
```

Comment: Line up your opening/closing brackets, parenthesis etc... and you will see what's missing. Also, what's this have to do with C# or javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count your brackets!

```
public class VorherbestimmungenActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView lv1;
    ArrayAdapter < String > adapter;
    EditText inputSearch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vorherbestimmung);
        String products[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.vorherbestimmung);
        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

                        String shareMessage = "";

                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, ""));
                        break;
                    default:
                        {

                            inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
                            adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
                            lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
                            inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {@Override
                                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                                    // When user changed the Text
                                    VorherbestimmungenActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                }
                            });
                        }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```